# Simulate Mouse on Android

Tags: android, mouse, root

Android has Mouse support and I wonder if I can control a "virtual mouse" via service/app. I did a lot of research but I do not think the sdk provides anything I can use for obvious security reasons.
I wonder if anyone could give me a hint how to achieve this with root permission.
If android phones can run a VNC server this should be possible too shouldn't it?
I want to send the movement of a computer mouse to the phone. A cursor should be shown like if you connect a bluetooth mouse.

Thank you